# Get two strings from the user. The program then replaces all the occurrences of second string from the first string, surrounded by quotes

Tags: python, string, replace

> Write a program that queries two strings from the user. The program then replaces all the occurrences of second string from the first string, surrounded by quotes.

I have this code, but it doesn't work:

```
def twoStrings():
    userInput1 = input('Give a first string: ')
    userInput2 = input('Give a second string: ')
    replacedString = userInput1.replace('userInput1', '"userInput2"')
    print('Replaced string: ', replacedString)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the variable and a f-string to have the real string to replace, not the literal string `userInput2`:

```
def twoStrings():
    userInput1 = input('Give a first string: ')
    userInput2 = input('Give a second string: ')
    replacedString = userInput1.replace(userInput2, f'"{userInput2}"')
    print('Replaced string: ', replacedString)
```

example:

```
Give a first string: test abc 1abc2
Give a second string: abc
Replaced string:  test "abc" 1"abc"2
```